# Ndepend Class Coupling Value exclude all classes not in my project

Tags: visual-studio, metrics, ndepend, coupling

I tried to calculate the class coupling with ndepend. But as far as I can see, all dependencies on other classes are added (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avUVB.png), so the ones from my Project: MultiCar, from mscorlib and System). I would like to only consider the types from my project and not the rest. Of course the value is given here, but I would like it to be directly calculated. Is there any why? I already tried to change the query shown at the top of the picture, but I am not familiar with it and did not find a good explanation on how to change it the way I want it to be. I really hope someone can help me.

The query is depicted in [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXzrc.gif).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so you need to edit the code query generated by the **[Search type by class coupling](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-search#Coupling)** panel.
[image: Edit Query of NDepend Search type by class coupling panel]

The query generated to edit manually is:

```
from t in Application.Types 
where t.NbTypesUsed >= 0 
orderby t.NbTypesUsed descending 
select new { 
   t,
   t.TypesUsed,
   t.TypesUsingMe
}
```

You just need to edit the `TypesUsed` line:

```
from t in Application.Types 
where t.NbTypesUsed >= 0 
orderby t.NbTypesUsed descending 
select new { 
   t,
   TypesUsed = t.TypesUsed.Where(tu => !tu.IsThirdParty),
   t.TypesUsingMe
}
```

Et voilà :)

[image: NDepend Search type by class coupling discard third-party types]